# Trying to run appropriate application for specified Manufacturer model using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to run the following programs, depending on the computer model. For now I have the below however nothing seems to run. Where am I going wrong?

## Determine if HP, Lenovo, or Dell

$Model = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | select Manufacturer

## Depending on Model, run appropriate program

If ($Model -eq 'LENOVO' ) {Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\System Update\tvsu.exe"}

ElseIf ($Model -eq 'Dell') {Start-Process "C:\Drivers\OEM\Setup\TEM_FOLDER\DellCommandUpdate_450\setup.exe"}

Comment: Try adding some logging. What value do you get for ```$Model```? Do the ```Start-Process``` lines even get called? What is the value of ```$LASTEXITCODE``` afterwards?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: [1] Just using `select  Manufacturer` will give you an **object** with one property called `Manufacturer`. This is not a string, so use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer`. [2] As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794337/trying-to-run-appropriate-application-for-specified-manufacturer-model-using-pow#comment128577339_72794337) commented, check what `$Model` contains. Your test with `-eq` is probably not good and you would want `-like '*Dell*'` most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently working on partly similar problem:

Lenovo:

```
$IsLenovo = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class Lenovo_BiosSetting -Errorvariable err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(IsLenovo -eq $null){....}
```

Fujitsu (and if i understand many others):

```
$manudacturer= Get-ComputerInfo -Property "CsManufacturer" 
            if( $manudacturer.CsManufacturer.Contains("FUJITSU")){...}
```

ps: in case you are thinking similar... calling "tvsu.exe /CM" + GPO, on logoff wont work(to long duration)